# Django dumpdata-loaddata error serializing custom class: ' Syntax error near "F" '

Tags: python, django, django-fixtures, loaddata, dumpdata

I'm trying to create a set of fixtures from my database using the `dumpdata` command provided by Django. I want to be able to load these fixtures using the `loaddata` command.

One of the Models I'm trying to dump has a custom field: particularly, I'm facing my problem with a field (of type MyHStoreField) that inherits from django.HStoreField. Django is incapable of serializing MyHStoreField.

```bash
django.db.utils.InternalError: Problem installing fixture '/fixture_files/fixture.json':
   Could not load MyModel: Syntax error near "F" at position 12
LINE 1: ...a_model_field" = '0.0000000000000000', "my_hstore_field" = '{"blabla...
```

From the Django docs, I think that what this class needs in order to be serialized is a custom JSONEncoder (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/serialization/#json-1). However, I don't know how to tell both `dumpdata` and `loaddata` to use this Encoder.

Is there any kind of registry that django uses in order to know which Encoders are available, or do I need to override the `loaddata` and `dumpdata` commands somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the problem was serializing the object, since in the file it has the wrong format:

```json
"my_hstore_field": "{\"blabla\": false}"
```

which is not a valid json but a string with a json format that Django doesn't know how to deserialize.

The solution has been postprocessing the file using a script just after running dumpdata, and saving that field as valid json:

```json
"my_hstore_field": {"blabla": false}
```